# *.cs.aspx cannot access *.cs files in App_Code folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

This site was developed a few years ago. it was working 100%. I am re-deploying to my pc to make some changes and testing. Now it cannot find those classes in those files. I have always used 4.5 Framework. I have searched for a solution, unfortunately those have not resolved my issue. including coping it into main directory. It worked when I copied the actual code into one of the *.cs.aspx files. However there are more then 20 pages using this email file. Any advice would be welcome. I have been scratching around for days. Thx.

===================ERROR========================>
The error is as follows:The type or namespace name 'Emailer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

===================ERROR-DISPLAY================>
Source Error:

---

### Heading

Answer (score 0):

As the message is saying you are most likely missing an Assembly reference. Look at the references of the old project (pic below) and make sure your new project has the same ones added.

[image]

If you locate any missing references you can add them by clicking on References > Add reference, and find it among the listed ones or browse to the physical path.

Answer (score 0):

Go to class property window by right clicking on it. Look for build option here Change your class build option to compile.

Answer (score 0):

You probably changed a Web Site Project to a Web Application Project. There are a [couple of differences between these project types](https://devio.wordpress.com/2010/07/30/differences-between-web-site-project-and-web-application-project/). Among them, in Web Application Projects, the App_Code directory seems to be ignored.